# Weird behavior with bound properies and direct visibility change in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged

I have a list of comments (with datatemplates). Some part of each comment is hidden (reply to comment box). I made a reply function that shows hidden reply part, user writes some message (in TextBox) then clicks a send button and an APP should hide this block after send. When I made it I stuck in a weird behavior. When I manage visibility of this hidden part of comment via visual tree i.e. directly change it in codebehind(after sending a message and adding it to a Observablecollection):

```
hiddenPart.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

It works as it should (message is added into list and I see it), but if I bind the visibility of the hidden part to a property in VeiwModel and change it via property, ListView (with these comments) scrolls to some offset up (after hiding reply part). Sometimes even to the top. 
ps. This option of ListView have no effect:

```
<ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"/>
```

I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: It looks like the problem is related with focus change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wierd problem has been related(99%) to navigation bug in Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 (when you should navigate between the pages via `Dispatcher` to avoid crashes).